# System.out.printf в Java

Tags: java

Мне надо выполнить следующее. Например если число трехзначное, то так и оставить. Если же оно однозначное или двузначное, то добавляем два нуля или один. Так вот, как это сделать в одну строку с помощью printf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить ведущие нули можно таким образом:

```
String.format("%03d", num);
```